# How to install valgrind 3.9.0 in centos 5.5

Tags: memory-management, centos, valgrind

I am trying to install valgrind on my CentOS-5.5-32bit, to check for memory issue in my source. As i am very unfamiliar with Linux, I couldn't do it myself and couldn't find any such commands by searching also.

I downloaded an extracted valgrind 3.9.0 using these commands. But don't know how to install and run my source under valgrind.

```
wget http://valgrind.org/downloads/valgrind-3.9.0.tar.bz2
tar xvjf valgrind-3.9.0.tar.bz2
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After Several attempts, i finally got it working. The steps i followed:

```
wget http://valgrind.org/downloads/valgrind-3.9.0.tar.bz2  //download valgrind
tar xvjf valgrind-3.9.0.tar.bz2                            //now extract
cd valgrind-3.9.0                                          //move to the corresponding dir
./configure                                                //prepare everything
make
make install                                               //now install
```

Now I can Execute my target executable under valgrind!

To execute under valgrind use:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes COMMAND_TO_RUN_MY_TARGET_EXECUTABLE
```

To Add origin information use:

```
--track-origins=yes
```

To save all the reports in a log file use:

```
--log-file="Valgrind_Report.txt"
```